# Answer is certainly not of "very bad quality"

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I don't know where or how I should say it, but I don't think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20015421) should have been deleted.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I agree.

If the answer is correct, it definitely shouldn't be deleted, just because it has a minimal explanation.

Of course the best answers are the ones that provide lots of details, ideally enlightening the reader how to solve similar problems in the future.

But if no such answer exists for the specific question, then one that gives the answer even without explanation is more valuable than nothing.

All this assuming the answer is correct. If It is wrong, there is little sense in keeping it.

Comment: When reviewing "Is this answer wrong?" is not something you should be asking yourself – you may not have the domain knowledge necessary. The question is, is it an attempt at an answer at all, and if yes, does it meet minimal quality standards with regard to formatting and content.

Comment: @O.O.Balance sure, but if you know it is totally wrong/irrelevant, there is little harm in casting a delete vote imo. On the other hand if you are unsure, I would err on the side of caution and let it stay.

Comment: On balance and at a glance, someone saying, "try this" to another person usually indicates *exploratory* answering as opposed to a definitive answer with a minimal explanation.  There's nothing definitive about an exchange like this since its very premise is steeped in trial and error, so correctness **cannot** apply.

Comment: @Makoto well if it works it works...

Comment: @user000001:  You then inspire a cargo cult of developers who copy "working" code from one place to another with no *inkling* on how that could be possible.

Comment: @Makoto no I never said that, but when examining if an answer should be deleted, the first consideration is if it can help someone in the right direction. It doesn't mean that the person using it will just copy paste it, he can do further research himself. Again, I am not saying that "try this" is the best answer, but it's can be sometimes helpful, when nothing better is available. There is also the case where OP had shown so little effort that you can't expect the answerer to do much better (not this case though).

Comment: @user000001 "There is also the case where OP had shown so little effort that you can't expect the answerer to do much better" – in that case, don't answer, vote to close instead.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't answer the question.  It just says "try this", which is *hardly* an answer.

Comment: it answers the question. "try this" is just a figure of speech. like noone here ever uses it

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  It *looks* like it's an answer but it really isn't.  It's throwing out two methods to attempt to use without any context into why those methods are necessary, what they do or what relevance they have to the problem at hand.  The answer as presented is less valuable any passer-by since it lacks critical context into what the actual issue was, and how it can be addressed.  This does *not* answer the question.

Comment: the question _is_ the context. i understand that the answer as is will not be fit for any passer-by, but it is well enough for me. and the useful information in it, the only hint to an answer is now lost for everyone. thanks for your time

Comment: @bobrobbob "the only hint to an answer is now lost for everyone" – nothing is stopping you (or anyone else that encounters this audit) from taking that hint and turning it into an actual answer with some context. You might even get some upvotes out of it.

Comment: @Makoto So whenever I've run across answers like this, I've applied [Cody's opinion about rhetorical questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131996/318307), which means editing the answer into "Do this" instead. Adding in a dash of [Undo's "You're doing it wrong" post](/q/287563/5764553) (looking at the rotten apple), if the answer merely suggests API methods with no context, wouldn't it be a target for downvoting/commenting/editing to add context, not deleting? Am I misunderstanding things?

Comment: @AndrewMyers I'm not sure what you are answering to here. Like.. were comments deleted? You sound like ranting, but I don't see the cause. The answer here does not seem to relate to what you are saying..

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Not ranting. (Try reading it with Spock's voice.) The answer in question was flagged as low-quality and then got deleted from review. bobrobbob here thinks it shouldn't have been deleted, but Makoto's answer says "It doesn't answer the question." My comment was toward that end. I'm genuinely curious to see if I've been doing things wrong.

Comment: @O.O.Balance i am well aware of that. but that rep belongs to the user that is not coming back. note that you're somehow saying the answer was salvageable.

Comment: @bobrobbob Not salvageable in the sense we use the word when reviewing. The information from the answer could have been used to write a good answer – but this would not have meant editing it to make it better – it would have amounted to writing a completely new answer. Hence the rep would be deserved. Look at it this way: You don't get rep for having the right idea, you get it for writing a good answer. An idea that may lead to an answer, a nudge in the right direction – that should be a comment. You don't get rep for those.